# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to build a chronometer but I'm having trouble calculating the delta_time

```
`def start():`
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(start_time)

def stop():
    stop_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    print(stop_time)
    delta_time = stop_time - start_time
```

When calling these functions i get:

```
2019-01-20 03:38:01.630833
```

`2019-01-20 03:38:05.790672`

```
File "test.py", line 15, in stop
    delta_time = stop_time - start_time
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'
```

I've looked around but found nothing that worked. I have no idea what might be causing this problem.

Comment: is `start_time` a global variable ? can't find it under `stop()` method?

Answer (score 0):

The error you are showing doesn't indicate that the issue is with variable scope, rather it is encountered based on calculations not being able to be done on non-like types.

It's difficult to say without seeing your full code, but perhaps the following will provide a possible alternative solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime

def start():
    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    return start_time

def stop():
    stop_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    return stop_time

def delta(start,stop):
    delta_time = stop - start
    print(delta_time)

start=start()
stop=stop()
delta(start,stop)
```

This solution moves the two generated timestamps (`start_time` and `stop_time`) into one single function (`delta`) as arguments so that when `delta_time` is calculated it is done on like-type variables within its function scope.