# Discord.py bot using datetime returns this (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int')

Tags: python, datetime, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Discord bot that counts the time elapsed since somebody said "word" but my current method returns the above error. I am very new to python and discord.py so please bear with me.

My search turned up [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54274151/11861092) but even with knowing why the error occurred, I'm not sure of any other way to go about this.

```py
import discord, os, re
import datetime
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime

token = ('')
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client = discord.client
start = 0
end = 0
elapsed = 0
elapsedstr = str

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is live")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if 'word' in message.content:
      global start
      start = datetime.datetime.now()
    await bot.process_commands(message)


@bot.command()
async def lastsaid(ctx):
    print('running lastsaid')
    global end
    global elapsed
    end = datetime.now()
    elapsed = end - start
    elapsedstr = datetime.now.strftime('%H:%M:%S', datetime.gmtime(elapsed))
    await ctx.send(('It has been ' + elapsedstr + ' since someone said the word!'))
    print('sent ls')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run(token)
```

How would I go about calculating the time elapsed without this error?

Comment: `elapsed = end - start` start is an integer (0) and end is a datetime object. start should probably be changed to a datetime object too

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure that start starts as a `datetime`object (currently it is starting at 0). Currently if something with `word` in it is not said before running your command then you will get the error. Also should `end = datetime.now()` be `end = datetime.datetime.now()`?